# Segfault when writing to cerr iostream, uclibc-ng unhandled exception

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, uclibc

The following code executes fine when compiled using GLIBC (g++ on Ubuntu 18.04). But when cross-compiling with a buildroot toolchain that uses uclibc with C++ support (g++), the result is a segmentation fault. Inspection of the core dump indicates an uncaught exception occurred.

I can't figure out why the uncaught exception and segfault occur. Any thoughts?

```bash
# aarch64 qemu environment 
./helloworld
Main entry.
Error trySegmentation fault
```

```bash
ulimit -c unlimited
./hellworold

Main entry.
Error trySegmentation fault (core dumped)

gdb -c core helloworld

# Core was generated by `helloworld'.
# Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
# #0  std::uncaught_exception ()
#    at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_catch.cc:141
```

```c
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        printf("\nMain entry.\n");
        try {
                std::cerr << "Error try" << std::endl;
        }
        catch (...) {
                std::cout << "Error catch" << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

```
# Makefile for main.cpp
CXX ?= g++
SOURCE_DIR += .
SOURCES += $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.cpp, $(SOURCE_DIR)))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SOURCES))
BIN := helloworld
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -ggdb -g3

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BIN)


$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.cpp
        @echo "CXX" $(CXX)
        @echo $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
        @echo [CXX] -c $< -o $@
        @$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(BIN): $(OBJECTS)
        @echo [LD] $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o $@
        @$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
        rm -f a.out helloworld
        rm -f *.o
```

**Update:**

It's possible this a uClibc-ng bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=106581

Statically linking with libstdc++ as mentioned resulted in correct behavior, no segfault.

Version info:
uclibc-ng 1.0.41
gcc version 11.3.0